# Error trying to install Googleway package

Tags: r, googleway

Been trying to install googleway for more than a week and it is just not working.

i have used the: `install.packages("googleway", dependencies= T)'`

```
install.packages("googleway",
                 repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages",
                         "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

i see it in my package list but when i try to call it with `library` it gives an error that another package is missing. the packages are : `mime` `jsonlite` `Rcpp`

tried installing these separately but still..

```
sessionInfo()
    R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:

[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

trying to install today was successful, `library()` command gave the below

```
library(googleway)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘googleway’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘shiny’
```

going back to the installation code:

```
package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

tried to seperately installing `'shiny'`, got the below error message when installation finished:

```
Error: invalid version specification ‘NA’
In addition: Warning message:
In utils:::packageDescription(packageName, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'knitr' was found
```

tried to call googleway after that:

```
    library(googleway)
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘googleway’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):

 there is no package called ‘htmltools’
```

i did try to install `knitr` still i get that a certain package is missing when i call `googleway`

note that i am able to download other packages and calling them successfully.

Comment: What is the exact output of `install.packages` and `library()`? If you tried installing the dependencies separately, did you get any error messages? What version of R and OS are you using (include your `sessionInfo()`.).

Comment: Can you load the other packages separately?

Comment: edited the question with the info.

Comment: I don't know why it's not installing the dependencies: have you tried to install `htmltools` manually too?

Comment: Yes, still i got `R6` as missing. I am not sure as well. i will try to uninstall and reinstall everything to rule out other hidden causes. thanks for the help and will keep you posted!!

Comment: If you find this to be an issue specific to `googleway` would you mind filing an issue report on [the github issue report page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with `googleway` as other packages started doing the same.

I uninstalled and reinstalled R and Rstudio then i reset R studio to desktop state using this link

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State